# Is there a way for easy construction of a list of repeated elements in Haskell without helper functions?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

Given a tuple of type `(Int, a)` such as `(n,c)`, I wish to construct a list `[a]` where the element `c` is repeated `n` times, i.e., `(4, 'b')` becomes `"bbbb"`. My current solution is the following:

```
decode :: (Int, a) -> [a]
decode (n, a) = map (\x -> a) [1..n]
```

As you can see, I'm mapping an anonymous function that always returns `a` over a list of `n` elements, the first n positive integers. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I feel bad about constructing a list of integers and never using it. Another solution would use a helper function and recurse down `n`, but that seems messy and overcomplicated. Is there perhaps something akin to the following python code?

```
'b'*4
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uncurry replicate`

```
Prelude> :t uncurry replicate
uncurry replicate :: (Int, b) -> [b]
Prelude> uncurry replicate (4, 'b')
"bbbb"
```

Comment: +1, but: while your solution gives him what he asked for, it does not give him what he needs. Id est: the XY problem :) Haskell programmers shouldn't use ``uncurry`` usually, that's more imperative style (I believe he asked like that, because he comes from Python).

Comment: @RamonSnir : I don't understand what you mean when you say the use of `uncurry` is considered imperative-style.

Comment: @gspr I really doubt he really needed `(Int, a) -> [a]`. He probably just need the functionality of `replicate`, so he should get used to using curried functions and not stick with Python-like syntax. It isn't imperative, but it is also a bad habit to use only tupled-functions.

Comment: @RamonSnir, where is my syntax Python-like? Is it because of the tuples? In my defense, I'm implementing a run-length encoder as an exercise from here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_about_lists     My encoding function is `encode xs = map compress (group xs)`, where `compress xs = (length xs, head xs)`. This is pretty close to the solution given; in the interest of avoiding the XY problem, could you give me a more Haskelly way of doing simple run-length encoding?

Comment: @Jake yes, for you specific case the ``uncurry`` is useful, I just suspected you might be sticking to Python habits (my fault! judged too quickly based on your mention of Python).

Answer (score 8):

There is a builtin [replicate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3areplicate) for that.

Check out [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+a+-%3E+Int+-%3E+%5ba%5d) for when you need to find if there is already a function that does what you want somewhere.

Comment: Wow, what an awesome way to search. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You want `replicate`.

A good way to find those things:
http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D

Comment: LOL, we need to find a way to play rock-paper-scisors now.